# Shift every values of a dataframe without changing columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the `pandas DataFrame` below:

```
pd.DataFrame(
    list(range(16,0,-1)),
    index=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P']
)
```

I would like to know if there is a `pandas function` that can allow me to shift by a number `x` the values of this dataframe in a way that: instance, if `x=3`, I get:

```
 D    E    F    G    H  I    J    K   L   M   N  O   P 
16   15   14   13   12  11   10   9   8   7   6  5   4
```

and makes sure that the last columns keeps the same order

Comment: `df.T.shift(3, axis=1)`? Transpose with shift

Comment: I appreciate, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though [@Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54673261/shift-every-values-of-a-dataframe-without-changing-columns#comment96136385_54673261)'s answer is intuitive and likely what you should use, I'll add my 2 cents.

#### `dropna` with `astype`

I don't like the conversion of integers to floats when shifting.  Also notice that I use `df.dtypes` in the `astype`.  This keeps it agnostic of what the types start out as.

```
df.shift(3).dropna().astype(df.dtypes).T

    D   E   F   G   H   I   J  K  L  M  N  O  P
0  16  15  14  13  12  11  10  9  8  7  6  5  4
```

This is problematic if there are pre-existing NA in the data.  In that case, I'd include an `iloc` to trim the first 3 rows explicitly.  But if that is the case then just use the next solution

---

#### `iloc` with `set_index`

```
df.iloc[3:].set_index(df.index[:-3]).T

    D   E   F   G   H   I   J  K  L  M  N  O  P
0  16  15  14  13  12  11  10  9  8  7  6  5  4
```

---

#### `pd.DataFrame`

```
pd.DataFrame(df.values[:-3].T, df.columns, df.index[3:])

    D   E   F   G   H   I   J  K  L  M  N  O  P
0  16  15  14  13  12  11  10  9  8  7  6  5  4
```

Comment: Nice one @piRSquared +1

Comment: @piRSquared new in `pandas 0.24` you can now have integer dtpyes with missing values. A great addition that I have been waiting for!  [What's new in 0.24.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html#optional-integer-na-support)

Comment: @Chris woot!  I’ll check it out

Answer (score 2):

As @chris mentioned,  transpose and shift() should work.

### You sample DataFrame:

```
>>> df
    0
A  16
B  15
C  14
D  13
E  12
F  11
G  10
H   9
I   8
J   7
K   6
L   5
M   4
N   3
O   2
P   1
```

### Output:

```
>>> df.T.shift(3, axis=1)
    A   B   C     D     E     F     G     H     I     J    K    L    M    N    O    P
0 NaN NaN NaN  16.0  15.0  14.0  13.0  12.0  11.0  10.0  9.0  8.0  7.0  6.0  5.0  4.0
```

### Edit:

Just in case you don't want Nan columns and floating numbers to be changed to Int.

```
>>> df.T.shift(3, axis=1).dropna(axis=1, how='all').astype(int)
 # df.T.shift(3, axis=1).dropna(axis=1).astype(int)
    D   E   F   G   H   I   J  K  L  M  N  O  P
0  16  15  14  13  12  11  10  9  8  7  6  5  4
```